# product personalization feature - upload image & text from frontend - module or theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, theme, product-view

We need `product personalization` feature, means we want customers to upload the product image and add text from frontend. then when he buy product, we will send a product with same image. 
[ ex product- T-shirts ]. For this we want to know which is better option:

1. Do we need to create new **module** and make one custom phtml page exactly looking like product view page and add options of **uploading image & text**.
2. We can create new theme. We can assign this theme to those custom products and add option of uploading image & text in product view page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to **create a new module** for this, because if you create module and if in future you would change theme, this feature will still be usable.

Also by creating theme, you can show these upload image or add text options to customers, but still to provide such functionality, you need to either create custom module or override core magento's functionality.

Comment: okay means creating one blank phtml page and make the page exactly look like `product view page` & adding options of `uploading image and text` is better option?

Comment: i thought of going for new theme  because it will save my time of `converting one custom phtml page to product view page`

Comment: Although it is upto you, but in my opinion it would be better to first create a custom module for it. You can't get customization functionality without module.

Comment: creating extra options of `uploading image and text` i again need to create module , thats fine. right now  i am worrying only about making one more custom product page that looks exactly like product view page. thanks a lot for your suggestion.